# What's the proper syntax to use for this NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm absolutely terrible at programming amd using stackoverflow atm, go easy on me, I'm trying to learn. From reading this code, what would be the proper syntax to use to avoid the NumberFormatExpection? `

```
package in.parapengu.spork.rotation;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import in.parapengu.commons.utils.file.TextFile;
import in.parapengu.spork.Spork;
import in.parapengu.spork.exception.rotation.RotationLoadException;
import in.parapengu.spork.map.MapLoader;
import in.parapengu.spork.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Rotation {

    private static int MAX_SIZE = 30;
    private static boolean OVERFLOW = true;

    private File file;
    private int index;
    private List<MapLoader> loaders;
    private List<RotationSlot> slots;

    public Rotation(File file, List<MapLoader> loaders, int index) {
        this.file = file;
        this.index = index;
        this.loaders = loaders;
        this.slots = new ArrayList<>();

        if(loaders.size() > MAX_SIZE && OVERFLOW) {
            for(MapLoader loader : loaders) {
                            try {


                slots.add(new RotationSlot(loader));
                            } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }    
            }
        } else {
                    try {
            while(slots.size() < MAX_SIZE) {
                for(int i = 0; i < loaders.size() && slots.size() < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
                    slots.add(new RotationSlot(loaders.get(i)));
                }

                if(slots.size() == 0) {
                    Log.warning("No slots were loaded");
                    break;
                } 
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }    
                }
    }

    public Rotation(File file, List<MapLoader> loaders) {
        this(file, loaders, 0);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public List<RotationSlot> getSlots() {
        return slots;
    }

    public boolean save() {
        TextFile file;
        try {
            file = new TextFile(this.file);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.exception(ex);
            return false;
        }

        file.line(index + "");
        for(MapLoader loader : loaders) {
            file.line(loader.getName());
        }

        file.save();
        return true;
    }

    public static Rotation parse(File file) throws RotationLoadException {
        if(!file.exists()) {
            throw new RotationLoadException(file, file.getName() + " does not exist");
        }

        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            throw new RotationLoadException(file, file.getName() + " was a directory");
        }

        List<String> lines;
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), Charsets.UTF_8);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RotationLoadException(file, ex);
        } 

        String first = lines.get(0);
        int index;
        try {
            index = Integer.parseInt(first);
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RotationLoadException(file, "The rotation index was not a valid number");

        } 

        lines.remove(0);
        List<MapLoader> maps = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String line : lines) {
            MapLoader loader = Spork.getMaps().getMap(line);
            if(loader == null) {
                throw new RotationLoadException(file, "Could not find a map matching \"" + line + "\"");
            }

            maps.add(loader);
        }

        return new Rotation(file, maps, index);
    }

}
```

`

Here's the error I get in console:
`

```
[06:27:59 WARN]: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1Test"
[06:27:59 WARN]:        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknow
n Source)
[06:27:59 WARN]:        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
[06:27:59 WARN]:        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
[06:27:59 WARN]:        at in.parapengu.spork.rotation.Rotation.parse(Rotation.j
ava:115)
```

`

Comment: Please only post relevant code. No one wants to read 200 lines of code that don't apply to the problem.

Comment: You haven't included line numbers, so it's very hard to see exactly where the failure is happening, but the problem is that you're passing "1Test" to `Integer.parseInt`; it's not a syntax problem. Only call `Integer.parseInt` on `Strings` that are just integers; if you need to parse a string that has other things in, you'll need to use a different method.

Comment: Exceptions should almost never be avoided, but rather handled correctly. This way you'll know where your code could potentially break and will minimize the amount of total code.

Comment: You might want to read [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about creating a minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for NumberFormatException is because, you are trying to convert alpha numerics String "1Test" to number.

Try removing all the characters from your string like:

```
String name ="1Test";//why are you reading string?
Integer number = Integer.parseInt(name.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
System.out.println(number);
```

You are catching the exception correctly and re-throwing RotationLoadException.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if you think it has helped and close this question so that it would help others in future.